# Why am I not able to instansiate new variables?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, instantiation

I was using AsyncTask class... My objective is to have a list and when search button is clicked make "Searching..." string appear in the list while searching... For that I tried to instansiate an adapter inside onPreExecute()

```
private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            String[] strings = new String[] { "Searching" };
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);


            mSearchButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
                //rest of methods
}
```

The compiler gives me an error in `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);`

And it says:`The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchActivity.SearchTask, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined`

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect parameters. Take a look at [documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this,      
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `SearchActivity.SearchTask` is not an `Activity` (or a `Context` in more general scenario) . You should use `SearchActivity.this` instead of simply `this` that is referring to an object of type `SearchActivity.SearchTask` subclass of  `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

Because your parameter is wrong 
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);

(context,int,object[])

you input 'this' but 'this' is not context.

If you use 'this' in SearchTask , it means not context.

so you use 'getparent()' instead of 'this'

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a problem of `this`.

add a member variable in `SearchActivity`:

```
private Context mContext = this;
```

and then change:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
```